# How to place multiple colorbars next to each other in the same axis automatically

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a plot (example here below) where I need to put multiple colorbars in the same axis

[image: Example plot]

To do that at the moment I have to create a new axis for every colorbar with values defined manually like so

```py
x_cbar_0, y_cbar_0, x_cbar_size, y_cbar_size     = 0.18, 0.05, 0.3, 0.02
x_cbar2_0, y_cbar2_0, x_cbar2_size, y_cbar2_size = 0.55, 0.05, 0.3, 0.02

ax_cbar = plt.gcf().add_axes([x_cbar_0, y_cbar_0, x_cbar_size, y_cbar_size])
ax_cbar_2 = plt.gcf().add_axes([x_cbar2_0, y_cbar2_0, x_cbar2_size, y_cbar2_size])
cbar_snow = plt.gcf().colorbar(cs_snow, cax=ax_cbar, orientation='horizontal',
 label='Snow')
cbar_rain = plt.gcf().colorbar(cs_rain, cax=ax_cbar_2, orientation='horizontal',
 label='Rain')
```

This is not really a portable solution as when something is changing, for example the map projection, the plot is slightly resized and I have to tune these numbers to manually place the colorbars without overlapping.

Isn't there a way to automatically create a new axis with the same width of the figure (I believe `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider` should do that) and then split it into an arbitrary number of sub-axes which can then be used to place the colorbars?

Comment: Why not [GridSpecs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mr. T said above, a gridspec is a pretty good way.  You may want to nest gridspecs for more complicated layouts, but:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)

gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 3, height_ratios=[1, 0.05], width_ratios=[1, 0.2, 1])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])

pc1 = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(20, 20), cmap='viridis')
pc2 = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(20, 20), cmap='RdBu_r')

cax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
fig.colorbar(pc1, cax=cax1, orientation='horizontal')

cax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, -1])
fig.colorbar(pc2, cax=cax2, orientation='horizontal', extend='max')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: mmm that's a good idea..I've used gridspec to have many figures together with different aspect ratios but never to add colorbars to a figure. i Just have to figure out how to adapt my code to do that..thanks